# Obstruction against the existence of a splitting in a fibered category

Tags: ct.category-theory

This is a bit imprecise, but reading about fibered categories and the existence of splittings, the following question came into my mind:

**Is there a way to define, for a given fibered category ${\mathcal F}\to{\mathcal C}$, an "obstruction" against the existence of a splitting, i.e. a cleavage compatible with identities and compositions?**

Even in the case of a fibered category associated to a surjective group homomorphism $G\to Q$ this is not clear to me; here, the question amounts to asking if there is some group cohomological obstruction against the existence of a splitting $Q\to G$.